# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent'.ts (2345)

Tags: angular, typescript, events, keyboard

I'm learning TypeScript and Angular and I've run into an example in my book that won't compile. I'm afraid I don't know how to fix the problem.

Here is the function that won't compile:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const logger = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup');
    logger.pipe(
      map((evt: KeyboardEvent) => evt.key.charCodeAt(0)),
      filter(code => {
        if (this.numeric) {
          return !(code > 31 && (code < 48 || code > 57));
        }
        return true;
      }),
      tap(digit => this.keys += String.fromCharCode(digit))
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

The specific line that won't compile is:

```
map((evt: KeyboardEvent) => evt.key.charCodeAt(0)),
```

I see the following error:

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<KeyboardEvent, number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, number>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just tell ts that this stream will be stream of keyboard events

```
const logger = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup');
```

this `<Type>` param makes logger `Observable<KeyboardEvent>` and ts won't complain about it